# How to seperate nested array from Map ? - Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have Map that consists of String and Object;

```
Map<String, Object> filters
```

And its structure is like;
[image]

But when I try foreach to **filters** , the value, which is **String array in Object**, becomes like `[ljava.lang.string;@46d8e9e`

I want to seperate that string array in Object from map and make foreach in that but all the things that I tried didn't work.

Here's my method to make foreach;

```
       if (!filters.isEmpty()) {
            filters.forEach((k, v) -> {
                columnName = new String(k.toString());
                filter = new String(v.toString());
            });
        } else {
            columnName = new String(DEFAULT_SORT_FIELD);
            filter = new String("");
        }
```

Actually, I'm using **selectCheckboxMenu** from **Primefaces** and this weird map comes from there. When I use **selectOneMenu**, **value** already comes like **key**.

Comment: It is not so clear to me if your problem is the 'weirdness' of the array, or the algorithm you try to apply to it.

Comment: Yes but I couldn't reach into that **'ANKARA'** value. I've tried so many ways to reach and seperate it, that's why I called it 'weird'.

Comment: I have some background info because I've read your previous questions. You have an http://xyproblem.info/ You really done want to convert the array to a string as the component you are using can give multiple values. At some point in your filter you need to do something like `and city in (val1, val2, val3)` when creating your query. Again, you really need an array and you don't want to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I've got you properly, you need to convert String[] which is kept in Object, that example will return *[a, b, c]*

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("key1", new String[]{"a","b","c"});

    map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(toList(v)));

  }

  public static List<String> toList(Object obj) {
    return Arrays.asList((String[])obj);
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: In other words: just cast the `Object` to `String[]`.